# local variable referenced by a global pointer

Tags: c

I have a question here. I have following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int *ptr;

int myfunc(void);
main()
{
   int tst = 3;
   ptr = &tst;
   printf("tst = %d\n", tst);
   myfunc();
   printf("tst = %d\n", tst);
}

int myfunc(void)
{
    *ptr = 4;
}
```

The local variables are stored in the stack. I made a global pointer `*ptr` and made it point to a local variable in `main`. Now, when I call `myfunc`, the local variables of `main` get pushed onto the stack. In `myfunc`, I change the value of `ptr` and after returning to `main`, I check the value of the local variable that has now changed.

In `myfunc`, is the pushed variable `tst` popped again for its value to be changed?

Comment: It works cleanly because your global pointer points to a local variable in `main()`, and simple local variables in `main()` like that `tst` don't go out of scope until the `main()` exits, so it remains valid for use via the global.  However, this is an unusual set of circumstances.  In general, avoid making global variables point to local variables; it is quite likely to lead to trouble and confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a functions call is made, not all variables are pushed onto the stack. Only those which are arguments of the functions will be pushed onto the stack, i.e: ones in parentheses, like this: `myfunc(arg);`. In this case, `arg` will be pushed onto the stack for use in `myfunc`. The key is to remember that in C its just the values in variables that are pushed, not the variable itself.

You might be after something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int *ptr;

int myfunc(int value);
int myfunc2(int *pValue);

int main()
{
   int tst = 3;
   ptr = &tst;
   printf("tst = %d\n", tst);
   myfunc(*ptr);
   printf("tst = %d\n", tst);
   myfunc2(ptr);
   printf("tst = %d\n", tst);

}

void myfunc(int value)
{
    //here you can do whatever you want with the value that was in the global ptr
    //but when you return to main it will not have changed.

    value = value + 10;       //has no effect on tst
}

void myfunc2(int *pValue)
{
    //here the argument is a pointer value. If you de-reference the pointer value
    //with an '*' you start accessing the contents at that address

    *pValue = *pValue + 10;    //does effect the global *ptr
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, tst is not "popped" again.  myfunc merely receives the address of where tst is located on the stack and updates the memory at that address.

Note that taking pointers to automatic (stack) variables and placing them in globals is generally a bad idea.  The pointers cease to be valid as soon as the function exits but the system will not detect that so memory corruption is likely.  Not a problem in this case but also not a good habit to get into.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you very much. I am not going to use this somewhere. I wrote that piece of code just to see what happens. You know playing with things always increase your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Since ptr is global, when you make it point to some object inside a function, it globally points to the memory location of that object.

You are updating the contents of that memory location in `myfunc()`, and then accessing the same memory location in `main()`. So obviously the change you made in `myfunc()` is visible.